# Laravel horizon : dont work problem redis

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

hello i want to send mails using laravel horizon but i have a problem when i execute the laravel horizon command.
I use laravel 5.7 on a windows 10
Here is the error below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB2j4.jpg)

Comment: That error is saying it can't connect to Redis.

Comment: Just curious. I have never seen exceptions translated like that before, where is that coming from since it looks like it is the default predis package?

Comment: @Stephan that's what I do not understand I did all the configuration and I installed laravel horizon that appears in the browser (dashboard) but I can not activate it with the php artisan horizon command